Error lint Unexpected token
Estoy haciendo una tarea de la escuela y nos piden que antes de hacer pull request ejecutemos Lint and Format, es decir npm run lint y npm run format. El problema parece estar en el archivo vite.config.js, pero ya revise el archivo y no note algún problema. Adjunto lo que tiene el archivo antes mencionado.
import { resolve } from 'path';
import { defineConfig } from 'vite';

export default defineConfig({
  root: 'src/',

  build: {
    outDir: '../dist',
    rollupOptions: {
      input: {
        main: resolve(__dirname, 'src/index.html'),
        cart: resolve(__dirname, 'src/cart/index.html'),
        checkout: resolve(__dirname, 'src/checkout/index.html'),
        product1: resolve(
          __dirname,
          'src/product_pages/cedar-ridge-rimrock-2.html',
        ),
        product2: resolve(__dirname, 'src/product_pages/marmot-ajax-3.html'),
        product3: resolve(
          __dirname,
          'src/product_pages/northface-alpine-3.html',
        ),
        product4: resolve(
          __dirname,
          'src/product_pages/northface-talus-4.html',
        ),
      },
    },
  },
});

Aún estoy en el proceso de aprendizaje y pues solicito su apoyo, si alguien tiene idea sobre como resolverlo. También adjunto una imagen con lo que me aparecio en consola.
Gracias!

